# MimeKit attachment body encoding issue

Tags: c#, encoding, mime, mimekit

I need to get all emails in mailbox.
And i need to read attachment's bodies to get info.
But i have encoding issue and can't solve this problem.

> Code sample:

```
            using (var client = new ImapClient()) 
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, b) => true;
                client.Connect("imap.secureserver.net", 143, SecureSocketOptions.Auto); // godaddy
                client.Authenticate("username", "password");


                client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                IList<UniqueId> uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);

                foreach (UniqueId uid in uids)
                {
                    MimeMessage message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

                    foreach (MimeEntity attachment in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        var fileName = "test" + Tools.GenerateRandomString(5);
                        if ((attachment is MessagePart))
                        {
                            var attachmentBody = ((MessagePart)attachment).Message.ToStringNullSafe();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Attachment Header:

> Content-Type: text/plain;charset="utf-8"
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

---

Encoding Issue In Attachment Body

> Subject: Bili=C5=9Fim A.=C5=9E.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop seems to be incomplete because a `MessagePart` cannot represent a `text/plain;charset="utf-8"` MIME part, so your code and your results do not match up.

That said, what you are seeing is that the content is encoded. You need to decode it:

```
if (attachment is MimePart) {
    part = (MimePart) attachment;

    using (var stream = File.Create (fileName))
        part.Content.DecodeTo (stream);
}
```